# SignalGenerator class at naudio library - duration time play

Tags: c#, signal-processing, naudio

I use naudio for generating a tone in a specified frequency like that:

```
private void gen_Sinus(double frequency)
    {
        WaveOut _myWaveOut = new WaveOut();

        SignalGenerator mySinus = new SignalGenerator(44100, 1);//using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders; 
        mySinus.Frequency = frequency;
        mySinus.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin;
        _myWaveOut.Init(mySinus);
        _myWaveOut.Play();
    }
```

I want that when clicking a button it will play that tone for a specific time that will be passed to this method. Let's call it for example:

```
double toneDuration
```

I prefer to prevent some sleep methods because it has to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OffsetSampleProvider` to do this, and set the `Take` duration:

```
var trimmed = new OffsetSampleProvider(signalGenerator);
trimmed.Take = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
waveOut.Init(trimmed);
waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: Hello, is there any class or something else that take care of the frequency transitions in the case of using more than 1 singalGenerator?

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer and a wait handler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        }
        static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        private void gen_Sinus(double frequency)
        {
            WaveOut _myWaveOut = new WaveOut();

            SignalGenerator mySinus = new SignalGenerator(44100, 1);//using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders; 
            mySinus.Frequency = frequency;
            mySinus.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin;
            _myWaveOut.Init(mySinus);

            timer1.Interval = 5000;
            timer1.Start()

            _myWaveOut.Play();
            autoEvent.Reset();
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
            _myWaveOut.Stop();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            autoEvent.Set();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Hello, I use WPF, where do I need to declare the timer1 object?

Comment: See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hello thanks for the link. I saw that if I use WPF the "timer" class there is called dispatcherTimer. Is it the same?